# MSSQL 2016 Package execution failed | SSIS error: Index was out of range

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-2016, copy-database-wizard

I've made a copy job with Copy Database Wizard using SMO(leave DB online). The DB is to be copied to the same SQL instance. This fails with

> The package execution failed.  The step failed.

If I execute the SSIS package it has created, the following occurs:

> Event Name: OnError  Message: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index StackTrace:    at System.Collections.BitArray.Set(Int32 index,
>   Boolean value)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PermissionWorker.GetPermissionSetBase(PermissionEnumKind
>   kind, Int32 i)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetPermissionsFromCache(PermissionEnumKind
>   kind)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AddScriptPermissions(StringCollection
>   sc, PermissionEnumKind kind, ScriptingPreferences sp)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database.AddScriptPermission(StringCollection
>   query, ScriptingPreferences sp)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptCreateSpecialUrn(Urn
>   urn, ScriptingPreferences sp, ObjectScriptingType& scriptType)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptCreate(Urn urn,
>   ScriptingPreferences sp, ObjectScriptingType& scriptType)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptCreateObjects(IEnumerable`1
>   urns)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptUrns(List`1
>   orderedUrns)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.DiscoverOrderScript(IEnumerable`1
>   urns)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptWorker(List`1
>   urns, ISmoScriptWriter writer)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.Script(UrnCollection
>   list, ISmoScriptWriter writer)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataTransferBase.GetScriptLoadedTransferWriter()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.TransferDatabasesUsingSMOTransfer()

I have tried starting the job from SQLCMD as well. Same results.
I have tried Detach/Attach method as well. That went through fine, however, that is not a desired option as it leaves the DB offline for the transfer's duration.

I have admin rights on the server(Windows) and the instance as well. 
Executing the package(.dtsx file using Package Execution Utility) outside SSMS gives the same error.
I have created an empty database with only one table in it. Same error happens.

Please help..

*OS: Windows Server 2012
MSSQL: 2016 SP1*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved with applying the January 2018 CU, even though this fix is NOT documented there.